# Why .Net Core has its own claim types?

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, coreclr

Based OpenidConnect specification the standard types for role claim and name claim is `role` and `name`. However in .net core `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.NameClaimType` is set to "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" and `System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType` is set to "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role"

My issue here is with role.

My ASP.NET core application is using OpenIdConnect for authentication. After successful authentication the OpenIdConnect provider sends back the role as a part of claims collection with `Cliam.Type` is set to `role` which is correct as per the OpenId specs.

However since .Net Core has its own type for role, `IsInRole()` method always returns false. Because I think `IsInRole()` method uses microsoft's role type for comparison.

Why .net is using differ types for claims instead of using standard convention? and how do I solve `IsInRole()` issue

**Update 1**

Well I tried configuring claim types during startup but it didn't work.

**startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        // some stuff here that is not related to Identity like building configuration
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);
        services.AddAuthorization();
        services.AddMvc(config =>
        {
            var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
            .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
            config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
        });

        // Add Kendo UI services to the services container
        services.AddKendo();

        // Transform Microsoft cliam types to my claim type
        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>(options =>
        {
            options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "role";
            options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "name";
        });

    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory, IApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {            
        loggerFactory.AddSerilog();
        appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(Log.CloseAndFlush);
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        app.UseApplicationInsightsRequestTelemetry();
        app.UseApplicationInsightsExceptionTelemetry();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseIdentityServer(Configuration["Identity:Authority"], Configuration["Identity:ClientId"], Configuration["Identity:PostLogoutRedirectUri"]);

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });

        // Configure Kendo UI
        app.UseKendo(env);
    }
}
```

**UseIdentityServer extension method**

```
    public static void UseIdentityServer(this IApplicationBuilder app, string authority, string clientId, string postlogoutRedirectUri)
    {
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
        {
            AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            AuthenticationScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            LoginPath = IdentityConstant.CallbackPath,
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString(IdentityConstant.AccessDeniedPath),
            CookieName = IdentityConstant.AuthenticationCookieName,
        });

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.DefaultInboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        var connectOptions = new OpenIdConnectOptions()
        {         
            AutomaticChallenge = true,
            Authority = authority,
            ClientId = clientId,
            ResponseType = IdentityConstant.ResponseType,
            AuthenticationScheme = IdentityConstant.OpenIdAuthenticationScheme,
            SignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = postlogoutRedirectUri,
            CallbackPath = IdentityConstant.CallbackPath,
            Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents()
            {
                OnTokenValidated = async context =>
                {
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(context.Options.Authority + IdentityConstant.UserInfoEndpoint);
                    var response = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(context.ProtocolMessage.AccessToken);
                    var claims = response.Claims;

                    //We will create new identity to store only required claims.
                    var newIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Ticket.Principal.Identity.AuthenticationType);

                    // keep the id_token for logout
                    newIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(IdentityConstant.IdTokenClaim, context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));

                    // add userinfo claims
                    newIdentity.AddClaims(claims);

                    // overwrite existing authentication ticket
                    context.Ticket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsPrincipal(newIdentity),
                        context.Ticket.Properties,
                        context.Ticket.AuthenticationScheme);

                    await Task.FromResult(0);
                }
            }
        };

        connectOptions.Scope.Add(IdentityConstant.OpenIdScope);
        connectOptions.Scope.Add(IdentityConstant.ProfileScope);
        connectOptions.Scope.Add("roles");

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(connectOptions);
    }
```

**Update 2**

I use IdentityServer3 for authentication for all our applications. If the client application is developed using classic ASP.NET MVC then ASP.Net's JWT handler will transform incoming `role` claim type to `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` *(More details can be found [here](https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/overview/mvcGettingStarted.html) under `Claims Transformation` section)*
However same is not true when client application is developed using ASP.NET Core. The .net core **WILL NOT** transform claimtypes to .Net claim type, and that is correct. However .Net Core internally uses .Net claim type to find is user's role claims.

That means I need to Transform .Net claim types to desired claim type, but not sure where?

Answer (score 1):

What are the standard conventions?  You're only thinking of it from the context of the OpenId Connect specification which is not the only identity standard out there.  Microsoft have made it generic enough to support all identity systems.

The fault here seems to be in the OpenId Connect authentication implementation for not providing a `ClaimsPrincipal` that uses the correct claim type for role.

Having said that you can fix it by implementing your own `ClaimsPrincipal` and override the `IsInRole()` method to use the correct claim type.

Comment: http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role this type is specific to Microsoft ..and these are standard claims  http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html#Claims

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively you might consider putting in a place some middleware to apply the appropriate role claims based on the OpenId claims coming back?

Comment: Good point, this can be done with the `UseClaimsTransformation` middleware.

Comment: Too complicated. Role, username, userid and security stap can be configured via IdentityOptions

Comment: I don't think we can use UseClaimsTransformation. It only allows to add new claims but you cannot change the type of existing claims in UseClaimsTransformation

Answer (score 1):

You can configure the claim types during application startup.

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options => {
        options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = "http://yourdesiredclaimtype";
        options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = "http://yourdesiredclaimtype";
});
```

You can see the [claim options](http://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/ClaimsIdentityOptions.cs) on GitHub.